# Search Functionality in TYPO3 FrontEnd

Tags: typo3

I am new to TYPO3. We have a requirement in TYPO3 site, need to enable a search feature in frontend. Are there any default search extensions, can any one suggest me how to install the plug in or how to enable search in TYPO3 website successfully. 
Thanks

Comment: please specify your TYPO3 version

Comment: I am using TYPO3 version 6.0.10

Comment: Then you might want to think about an upgrade to 6.2 LTS, as 6.0 is not maintained anymore, see typo3.org/typo3-cms/roadmap/ - try it on a test instance first, of course. And please accept the answer with the check icon if it helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default TYPO3 search extension is `indexed_search`. It is delivered with TYPO3, but I've [read](http://forum.typo3.org/index.php/t/201402/alternative-f-r-indexed-search-auf-6-2) that it's not very much maintained anymore.

I used to find the configuration confusing, that's why I switched to `ke_search` from http://kesearch.kennziffer.com which is [well documented](http://kesearch.kennziffer.com/en/documentation/introduction.html) and does a nice job. The difference is that `indexed_search` works as you'd expect it from Google: it crawls pages and documents (which can slow up the site) via the frontend and indexes them. `ke_search` indexes by the database and file system. That's why it's much faster, cleaner - but only regular content and the most important extensions (like news) are covered. You can add own database tables by [writing an own indexer](http://kesearch.kennziffer.com/en/documentation/write-your-own-custom-indexer.html), though. Despite that restriction, I can absolutely recommend ke_search over indexed_search.

For cutting edge search, [SOLR](https://forge.typo3.org/projects/extension-solr/wiki) is used, but it won't run on regular shared hostings (at least on the ones I use).

Comment: Thanks Urs for solution

Answer (score 0):

I'd really recommend using some of the SaaS search providers. [Algolia](https://www.algolia.com/) or [Swiftype](https://swiftype.com/). Algolia provides quite reasonable Free Plan, which should be enough for most websites. There are more providers, such as Google etc.

According to my personal experience I'd definitely go with Algolia here - their customer support is also really good!